# tool that plots the network of hypertext links on a website with readable and clickable page titles?

Tags: wordpress, graph, hyperlink, content-management-system, diagram

I am trying to locate a tool that will generate an **interactive diagram of the links on a website I am creating so that a visitor can use that diagram as a navigation aide**. Similar to what mind-mapping apps do, but displaying the contents of my site instead. A simple example of what I have in mind (found on [this page](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2011/02/23/visualizing-link-flow)):

[image]

I have found many SEO tools that let me visualize the link structure on a site, but they

1. are meant to be used offline by site admins and
2. typically display each page as a just a colored dot (lacking the page title).

I am looking for something that can be used to display a graph of the links on my site to the user and can conveniently be used by the visitor to navigate the site.

A good example of what I have in mind is the [graph view](https://obsidian.md/images/screenshot-1.0-hero-combo.png) in the note-taking app Obsidian.

Do you know of any similar tool? I am happy to create my site on a particular CMS platform (WordPress, etc.) if the best tool for this is a CMS-specific plugin.